Golang slog: how to recreate the log file when standard logger output redirected to file and if it's deleted while program is running?
package main

import (
    "log/slog"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    file, _ := os.Create("log.txt")
    opt := &slog.HandlerOptions{}
    handler := slog.NewTextHandler(file, opt) //redirecting log output to "log.txt"
    logger := slog.New(handler)
    for {
        logger.Info("info message")
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

During running the specified code, I delete the log file "log.txt".
The program continues to work without issuing error messages, but logs are no longer written to the file.
Is there a solution to recreate the log file, or some other way to correctly work with the output of loggers to files with slog package?
P.S. there is an option with blocking log-file from deletion with syscall.Flock, but I would like to find a solution with recreating the file.

Assuming you are on a Unix-based system (Mac/Linux/BSD) not really. The file is still there and being written to, it just isn't available from the directory listing any more. This is a deliberate behaviour. You could periodically check if you can still see the file and reopen itI suppose.
